# Can you lock on a generic dictionary?

Tags: c#, multithreading, generics, dictionary, locking

Or should you always create some other lock object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, cast it to an IDictionary and lock on `.SyncRoot`:

```
Generic.Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Generic.Dictionary<int, int>();

lock (((IDictionary)dic).SyncRoot)
{
    // code
}
```

Thanks to this [source](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Generics_Recipes%E2%80%94Replacing_the_Hashtable_with_Its_Generic_Counterpart) for the info.

Of course a thread-safe dictionary would be nice, too, as others have suggested.

Comment: This answer was Accepted, but anyone who read this should also take a look on this for example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327654/hashtable-to-dictionary-syncroot . SyncRoot is not the best way to lock on collections.

Comment: I realize this answer is old. Just wanted to tell you the link is dead now.

Comment: Its better to not use "SyncRoot", it was a design problem by .net team, use Lock(_lockObject) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can lock on any object that you wish (except value-types). It's **recommended** though to lock on the .SyncRoot object.